# How to initialize a TypeScript object from a list of constructors? (Maybe: Mapped Type? Type operator for opposite of `typeof`?)

Tags: typescript, types

In TypeScript `class Foo {}` produces the name declaration `Foo` which is the type of an instance of the class `Foo`, and it produces the variable `Foo`, which is the constructor function for the `Foo` class. ([TypeScript Declaration Spaces](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/master/docs/project/declarationspaces.md).) Given the value `Foo` (the constructor function) one can use the `typeof` operator to get the type of the class (rather than the type of an instance of the class).

Summary:

```
Code            Variable Declaration         Name Declaration
--------------- ---------------------------- ----------------
class Foo {}    variable Foo                 type Foo
typeof Foo      type of variable Foo
```

What I want to know: given the type of the variable `Foo`, is there a compile-time operator to get the type `Foo`, the type of an instance of the class `Foo`?

**Or, more generally, how can I tersely describe the return type of `getWhatIWant` (below)?**

Consider:

```
class Base {
  constructor(someArgument: string) {}
}

class A extends Base { _brand: 'A' }
class B extends Base { _brand: 'B' }
class C extends Base { _brand: 'C' }

let allOfTheLetters = { A, B, C };
```

I want an object with constructor names as keys, and an instance of each class as the value. The literal version is:

```
let whatIWouldLike = {
  A: new A('same params'),
  B: new B('same params'),
  C: new C('same params')
}
```

I'm trying to transform `allOfTheLetters` into `whatIWouldLike`. It's no trouble in JavaScript - iterate over the keys and values:

```
function getWhatIWant(letters) {
  let result = {};
  Object.keys(letters).forEach((key) => result[key] = new letters[key]('same params'));
  return result;
}
```

How can I describe the return type of this function? Mapped types get me close:

```
type TypeIWant = {[key in keyof typeof allOfTheLetters ]: typeof allOfTheLetters [key]};

let example: TypeIWant;
let test: 'B' = example.B._brand; // Error: Property '_brand' does not exist on type 'typeof B'
```

`example.A` has type `'typeof A'`, not `'A'` like I need.

If `instanceof` was a compile-time operator that could transform types, then I could transform the type `'typeof A'` to `'A'` and I'd get what I want. But that's not how it works.

**How can I describe the type of the object returned by the `getWhatIWant` function without writing out every key-value pair like I did to create `whatIWouldLike`?**

[TypeScript Playground (same code as in this question)](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(someArgument%3A%20string)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20extends%20Base%20%7B%20_brand%3A%20%27A%27%3B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20Base%20%7B%20_brand%3A%20%27B%27%3B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20C%20extends%20Base%20%7B%20_brand%3A%20%27C%27%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20allOfTheLetters%20%3D%20%7B%20A%2C%20B%2C%20C%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getWhatIWant(letters)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20let%20result%3A%20any%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20Object.keys(letters).forEach((key)%20%3D%3E%20result%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20new%20letters%5Bkey%5D(%27same%20params%27))%3B%0D%0A%20%20return%20result%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20TypeIWant%20%3D%20%7B%5Bkey%20in%20keyof%20typeof%20allOfTheLetters%20%5D%3A%20typeof%20allOfTheLetters%20%5Bkey%5D%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20example%3A%20TypeIWant%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test%3A%20%27B%27%20%3D%20example.B._brand%3B)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're pretty close with mapped types.  Let's look at your classes:

```
class Base {
    constructor(someArgument: string) {}
}

class A extends Base { _brand: 'A'; }
class B extends Base { _brand: 'B'; }
class C extends Base { _brand: 'C'; }

let allOfTheLetters = { A, B, C };
```

Okay, so all your classes have a constructor that takes a single `string` argument.  Let's describe that:

```
type BaseConstructor<T> = new (someArgument: string) => T;
```

Now let's describe the type of `allOfTheLetters` as a function of the output you want from `getWhatIWant()`.  Yes, I'm doing it [backwards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types).  If the output is an object whose values are instances, the input is an object whose values are constructors for those very same instances, mapped by key:

```
type DictionaryOfConstructors<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: BaseConstructor<T[K]>
}
```

Now we can define the type of `getWhatIWant()`:

```
function getWhatIWant<T>(letters: DictionaryOfConstructors<T>): T {
  let result: any = {};
  // note I have to assert that `key` is `keyof T` below
  Object.keys(letters).forEach((key:keyof T) => result[key] =
    new letters[key]('same params'));
  return result;
}

let example = getWhatIWant(allOfTheLetters);
let test: 'B' = example.B._brand; // it works!
```

---

The reason this works is because it's easier to describe the constructor type given the instance type (`T` becomes `new(...)=>T`) than it is to describe the instance type given the constructor type (there's nothing like `typeof new C(...)` in TypeScript, [for now anyway](https://github.com/microsoft/typescript/issues/6606)) And luckily [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) is there to handle the backwards mapping for us.

Hope that helps; good luck!